# How can I sum negative and positive value separately in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the google sheets, I have a bunch of negative and positive amounts in the same vertical rows. Now in a particular cell, I want to show all the sum of positive values and in another cell, I want to show the sum of all negative values. I want to calculate the total debit and credit amount actually.

Here are some sample data I wanna calculate
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9PEW.png)

Any help will ve appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 6):

for negative values

```
=sumif(range, "<0")
```

for positive values

```
=sumif(range, ">0")
```

Answer (score 2):

For data in column **A** from **A1** to **A100**, try:

```
sumproduct((A1:A100)*(A1:A100>0))
```

and for the negatives:

```
sumproduct((A1:A100)*(A1:A100<0))
```

*(the second formula will yield a negative value)*
*(will also work for Excel)*